# I want to read email body and attachment from windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

I am able to read the phone no, subject, sender, and date and time and i need some help on reading the body of the email, i know that it can be read using openproperty but not able to move far.. hope help from u people thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to post some of the code you have so far, and definitely tag this with the programming language you're using.  This was flagged for migration to superuser.com, but I suspect it really is a programming question that should remain here.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked that carefully, so I'm not sure if it'll be useful (and your question isn't really very detailed either), but [this](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Pocket+pc+network+programming/Chapter+11.+E-mail/Common+Tasks+with+MAPI/) site seems to have some interesting sample code, including for getting out the body and the attachments. The title of the page is *Common Tasks with MAPI*.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will have a look and let u know if it solve my problem and sorry for not very detailed question. thans a lot by the way